# '$' is not defined

Tags: html, css, reactjs, slick.js

делаю сайт с помощью компонентов React.js.
В отдельный компонент хочу вставить [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) для слайдера, для него нужен JQuery и сам файл скрипта slick.min.js. и css файлы. Их я подключаю через ссылки внутри html.index.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- стили slick -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
  
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <!-- скрипты нужны для slick -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

потом создаю скрипт scroll.js

```
$('document').ready(function(){
      $('.roadmapSlider').slick({
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      });});
```

и импортирую этот скрипт в index.js. Подключаю его сюда, потому что не могу подключить напрямую через index.html, ведь для этого нужно создать папку script в public(а это нарушит build когда я закончу разработку)

```
import './script/scroll';
```

потом создаю новый компонент и подключаю его в App.js

```
import React from 'react';
export default ()=>(
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="slider">
                <div className="slider__item">
                    <img src="./img/bapticker(1).png" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div className="slider__item">
                    <img src="./img/bapticker(2).png" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div className="slider__item">
                    <img src="./img/bapticker(3).png" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
)
```

Запускаю, и вроде все должно работать, но почему-то выскакивает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR


src\script\scroll.js
  Line 2:1:   '$' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 4:3:   '$' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 61:7:  '$' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

пробовал переставлять местами подключения в index.html и это помогало, не выскакивало никаких ошибок, до первого изменения скрипта, потом опять появлялась эта ошибка. Буду благодарен если поможете :)

Comment: в head не пробовали переносить ссылки на скрипты?

Comment: пробовал, оно вроде работает, но если изменяешь скрипт то опять '$' is not defined

Comment: Попробуйте импортировать знак доллара из jQuery в файле, где ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Есть две частые причины:

1 **Не подключен jQuery**(Скорее всего):

*Файл не найден*, и таких ситуаций бывает очень много, даже если Вы полностью уверены что он подключен. Лучше перепроверять ещё раз

2 **Конфликт**

И пусть в данном случае другая ошибка отображается, но лучше помнить что `$` это спец.символ который может обозначать и другие дополнения, лучше всего подключать Jquery так: `jQuery({yourcode})` Это может быть очень полезно, когда надо добавить ещё что-нибудь, иначе зачастую приходится переделывать очень много кода.